# Cucumber/Gherkin tests ignored by TestNG but works with JUnit

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I have a test example using Cucumber+JUnit and is working properly. But then I changed it to work with TestNG and the scenarios are not being found. When I execute in Eclipse the test with TestNG (Run as -> TestNG Test) I get this message:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1 abr 14, 2020 1:36:06 PM
>   io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner  ADVERTENCIA: By default
>   Cucumber is running in --non-strict mode. This default will change to
>   --strict and --non-strict will be removed. You can use --strict or @CucumberOptions(strict = true) to suppress this warning abr 14, 2020
>   1:36:06 PM io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier get
>   ADVERTENCIA: No features found at
>   classpath:/com/other/cucumber/testrunner
>
> 0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0,000s

I found weird that it says:

> ADVERTENCIA: No features found at
>   classpath:/com/other/cucumber/testrunner

Whilst my runner class is configured to look for .feature files on com/other/cucumber/feature as you can see next:

**com.other.cucumber.testrunner.CucumberIntegrationTest**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:com/other/cucumber/feature",
        glue="com.other.cucumber.stepdefinition",
        tags = {"@RegressionTest"},
        plugin = {  "pretty",
                    "html:target/cucumber/concatTest",
                    "json:target/cucumber/concatTest.json"})
public class CucumberIntegrationTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

The .feature file is placed in src/test/resources/com/other/cucumber/feature and is found by JUnit (when executed by JUnit) but is not found by TestNG.

**TestNG.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >  
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >  
    <test name="Nopackage">  
        <classes>  
            <class name="com.other.cucumber.testrunner.CucumberIntegrationTest" />  
        </classes>  
    </test>  
</suite>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

After a lot of trial/error work I got it to run with TestNG but I had to downgrade my Cucumber dependencies from current `io.cucumber` to former `info.cukes`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

What do I need to run the latest versions of Cucumber with TestNG?

Comment: Remove `cucumber-junit` from your dependencies and you'll see the problem.

Comment: The weird message is not displayed anymore but scenarios are not being found anyway (using cucumber-java and cucumber-testng from io.cucumber). Using the info.cukes versions I haven't the problem.